# Running Python script from Excel using vba (working with network paths) - Module Not Found Error

Tags: python, excel, vba

I am trying to run a Python script from Excel VBA. The script and the excel workbook are saved in different network folders.

The script works when run in VS Code or Jupyter (python37).

For the purpose of testing the macro, I am currently using a simpler script (see below).

```
import pandas as pd

test = {'clmn1': ['a','b'], 'clmn2': [1,2]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(test)

df.to_excel('test_script.xlsx')
```

I have tested different solutions but I cannot make it work.
The one below returns ModuleNotFoundError for pandas.

```
Dim shell As Object
Dim exePath, scriptPath As String

Set shell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

exePath = """< python exe path>"""
scriptPath = "<python script network path>"

shell.Run "cmd /k" & " " & exePath & " " & scriptPath
```

I would be happy with any other solution that allows me to press a button in excel and run the script.

Comment: You should be able to accomplish this by `shell.Run "py """ & scriptPath & """"`.  `ModuleNotFoundError` sounds to me you are using a `venv` of some sort?

Comment: Hi r.ook! I am new to coding so forgive me. I developed the script in VSCode with Python3. Is there a way to run it as Jupyter notebook or in VSCode instead of Python 3 from the command line? I think that is why it cannot find the packages.

Comment: That's not what I mean.  If you see `ModuleNotFoundError` for a module like `pandas`, it probably means your PATH environment probably isn't set up right, or you're using a `venv` and forgot to activate it.  It would also help if you included a snippet of your python script in the question, so that a [mre] is shown.

Comment: I added the path environment "C:\Program Files\Python37" to control panel->user accounts->change my env variables. I cannot add it to control panel->systems->advanced system settings because I do not have the admin rights to access it. I will check if the venv is active.

Comment: The solution was to activate the environment, thanks!